# writing a shell script if statement to check for directory

Tags: shell, package, uninstallation, dpkg

I need to write a script that will recreate my opt folder if it gets deleted when I remove a package from it. Here's a link to my previous post: [dpkg remove to stop processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148273/dpkg-remove-to-stop-processes)

Now, the issue I'm running into could be better described here: http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2006/03/msg00242.html

I was thinking of just adding a postrem script which checks if an opt directory exists, and if not, creates one. My experience with shell scripts is pretty limited though..

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir -p "$dir"
```

This could be written more verbosely / clearly as:

```
if ! test -d "$dir"; then
    mkdir -p "$dir"
fi
```

See `help test` for more information.

Comment: Since `mkdir -p $dir` is idempotent, there's no need to test for the directory first. Just `mkdir -p "$dir"` is sufficient.

Comment: You're right.  I'm going to leave my answer as is though, because it illustrates a useful construct.