# How to solve Genivi RVI project installation error?

Tags: python, c#, android, embedded, automotive

I am trying to install RVI on Ubuntu 14.04 following the given installation instruction. I got the following error after running  "sudo dpkg -i rvi_0.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb":

```
(Reading database ... 174112 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rvi_0.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
 * Stopping Remote Vehicle Interaction Node... rvi                              Node rvi@osboxes not responding to pings.
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rvi, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
 * Stopping Remote Vehicle Interaction Node... rvi                              Node rvi@osboxes not responding to pings.
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rvi, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive rvi_0.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rvi_0.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Could you let me know what could have gone wrong?

Thank you

Comment: you are trying to reinstall package which is already installed in your system. You can try to comment out faulty code in /var/lib/dpkg/info/rvi.prerm to complete removal (before clean new install) or [use  --force-all flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346697/12396017)

Comment: Before re-installation, I tried to run a test to register a service as "hello", but it failed. this is the error I got: (socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused)